# find the max of an attribute per element in xml?

Tags: xml, database, xquery

I've been searching for the past hour on how to find the max of something grouped by an element to no success.

I'm trying to report the pid and the uid and the playcount of the playlist with the highest playcount PER user

here is my xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE users SYSTEM "users.dtd">
<users>
 <user uid = "u1" dob = "06/03/94" email = "tom@hotmail.com">
    <surname> Doe</surname>
    <givennames> Jon </givennames>
    <follows who = "u1 u2"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p1" created ="12/03/11" playcount = "5" /> 
    </playlists>
   </user>

  <user uid = "u2" dob = "06/03/95" email = "jane@hotmail.com">
    <surname> Dod</surname>
    <givennames> Jane </givennames>
    <follows who = "u1 u3"/>
   </user>

   <user uid = "u3" dob = "06/04/95" email = "dave@hotmail.com">
    <surname> ron</surname>
    <givennames> dave </givennames>
    <follows who = "u1 u2"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p3" created ="12/02/09" playcount = "9"/> 
      <playlist pid = "p9" created = "11/11/11" playcount = "11"/>
     </playlists>
   </user>

   <user uid = "u4" dob = "06/04/99" email = "jeff@hotmail.com">
    <surname> dun</surname>
    <givennames> jeff</givennames>
     <follows who = "u1 u2 u3"/>
    <playlists>
      <playlist pid = "p4" created ="12/02/09" playcount = "3"/> 
      <playlist pid = "p6" created ="12/02/09" playcount = "55"/>
    </playlists>
   </user>

</users>
```

I've tried doing

```
for $user in doc("users.xml")/users/user
 where $users/playlists/playlist/@playcount = max($users/playlists/playlist/@playcount)
   return $user
```

BUT it doesn't work..nothing i've tried has worked...it either returns me the max playcount per user (which is the best i've gotten since that's kinda the idea of what I want out of this query) or I get every playlist

I need a query which outputs:

```
<favorites>
   <user uid = "u1" pid = "p1" playcount = "5"/>
   <user uid = "u2" />
   <user uid = "u3" pid = "p9" playcount = "11"/>
   <user uid = "u4" pid = "p6" playcount = "55"/>
</favorites>
```

playlists is an optional element so if the user doesn't have a playlists then just report the uid..

any help? really at my wits end here because It seems so hard to find an example of finding a query which uses the max function grouped by an element..

Comment: XQuery 1.0 or XQuery 3.0? Version 3.0 has a "group by" construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to branch cases, and also customize the output format. Here is my xquery:

```
let $users := doc("users.xml")/users/user
for $user in $users
let $maxCount := max($user/playlists/playlist/@playcount)
let $maxPlaylist := $user/playlists/playlist[@playcount = $maxCount]
return if (count($maxPlaylist) > 0)
then <user uid="{$user/@uid}" pid = "{$maxPlaylist/@pid}" playcount = "{$maxPlaylist/@playcount}"/>
else <user uid="{$user/@uid}"/>
```